# Product image loads on all products page, but not on individual product page (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

For a little bit of context, when you add a new product to my website, you are required to add an image as well. I can get the product images to load just fine when viewing the main products page, but when you try to view an individual product on a new product details page, the image won't load.

The product image is pulled in via the following code:

```
<div class="product" style="background-image: url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.image }}')"></div>
```

Here is the HTML used on the main products page:

```
<div class="album">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="product-row">
                {% for product in products %}
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                        <div class="product" style="background-image: url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.image }}')"></div>
                        <div class="product-card-body">
                            <p class="product-title">{{ product.name }}</p>
                            <p class="text-muted">{{ product.category }}</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' product.id %}">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="product-btns btn-success" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <form class="ml-2" method="post" action="{% url 'product_details' product.id %}">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="product-btns btn-info" type="submit">Find out more</button>
                </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <p class="product-price">£{{ product.price }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the HTML used on the product details page:

```
<section class="container panel-body-forum-details">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>{{ products.name }}</h3>
            <hr>
            <p>{{ products.description }}</p>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="product" style="background-image: url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.image }}')"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p><strong>Service Type:</strong> {{ products.category }} </p>
            <p><strong>Price:</strong> £{{ products.price }} </p>
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Back to Services</a>
            {% if request.user == products.prod_creator_id %}
            <a href="{% url 'edit_product' products.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Edit Service</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=38, default='')
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=25, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Just an FYI, the product name, description, category and price all populate fine on the product details page. It's only the image that doesn't load.

Please let me know if you need anything else!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a copy and paste error to me:
details page:

```
{{ products.name }}
```

but:

```
{{ product.image }}
```

I think it should be "product**s**.image".